# RailsAdmin papertrail empty history

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I have configured RailsAdmin to use papertrail for showing the history of changes on models.

It seems to be working fine, but in the UI it displays changes always as an empty array.  Is this the expected output?  I was expecting to see the actual changes made on the records, or even better a drill down with a before and after change on the record.

- Rails 4, RailsAdmin 0.5, PaperTrail 2.7.2

[image: RailsAdmin History Tab]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a column called `object_changes`in your versions table.

See [these instructions](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/tree/2.7-stable) from paper_trail. Look at the section called "Diffing Versions."

In short, when you generate the versions table, do this `rails g paper_trail:install --with-changes`

Or, if you already have an objects table, do this migration:

```
class AddObjectChangesColumnToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :versions, :object_changes, :text
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :versions, :object_changes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the exact same thing and filed a bug report with rails_admin: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1751

If that is addressed I'll update this comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).